# Can't remove Ubuntu Desktop from dropdown menu on logon screen

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, gdm, session

I'm running Ubuntu on an Eee PC with the Netbook interface. I installed Ubuntu Desktop via Aptitude to see how well it works on the Eee PC, and after a while I wanted to rid myself of it. So, I purged it using Aptitude, but it still shows up as an option in the dropdown menu on the login screen.

Is there any way I can remove the Ubuntu Desktop option from the dropdown menu? It's not a big deal I guess... I'm just curious now how to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the list by editing the files located at `/usr/share/xsessions`, i don't know exactly what package sets up the Ubuntu Desktop entry, but i guess that you can backup the `Ubuntu Desktop Edition` file and delete it. Just run the following command:

`sudo cp "/usr/share/xsessions/Ubuntu Desktop Edition" /home/$USER/ubuntu-desktop-entry.backup && sudo rm "/usr/share/xsessions/Ubuntu Desktop Edition"`

Comment: Thanks Sebikul, that worked perfectly. And just an FYI, the name of the files I removed were gnome.desktop and gnome-failsafe.desktop. Thanks!

Comment: @bryan, in my installation the filenames are as i posted, weird. But anyway, you could solve your problem